# Updating UILabel text in custom cell

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

In my UITableViewController there are custom cells populated from JSON. Each cell has a `UILabel` showing a text value (`@"valoracion"`). When the user selects a row, a detail view from the cell object is shown. At this detail view, the user can change the value of `valoracion`. If the user goes back to the `UITableViewController`, `valoracion` should show the new value, but actually it shows the old value.

What should  I do to update `valoracion` in the `UITableViewController`, when the user goes back from the detail view to the `UITableViewController`.

UPDATED*****

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell ==nil){
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }

    //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    cell.nombreEmpresaLabel.text = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"nombreEmpresa"];



    //[[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];


    //cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = nil;
    // cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor=nil;
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  cell.direccionEmpresaLabel.text= [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"direccionEmpresa"];


    NSMutableString *logo = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/logos/"];
    NSString *imageURL = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"strImagen"];


    cell.meGustaHits.text = [[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"valoracionEmpresa"];




    if(imageURL != nil && ![imageURL isEqual:[NSNull null]])
    {
        [logo appendString:imageURL];
        NSURL *logoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:logo];
        NSData *logoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:logoURL];
        cell.logoImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:logoData];
    }
    else{
        cell.logoImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icono80"];
    }



    return cell;
}
```

Inside viewDidLoad method:

```
//URL definition where php file is hosted

    int categoriaID = [[categoriaDescription objectForKey:@"idCategoria"] intValue];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", categoriaID];
    NSLog(@"CATEGORIA ID STGRING %@",string);
    NSMutableString *ms = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http://mujercanariasigloxxi.appgestion.eu/app_php_files/empresaslist.php?id="];
    [ms appendString:string];
    // URL request
    NSLog(@"URL = %@",ms);
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ms]];
    //URL connection to the internet
    [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

And now the JSON delegate methods and didSelecRowAtIndexpath method:

```
//methods to perform the connection and population of data

-(void)connection: (NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

    data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)thedata
{
    [data appendData:thedata];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //if data received network indicator not visible
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

    //array waterfalls populated via JSON from database
    categorias = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    NSLog(@"THE DA TA &@",categorias);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

//only in case of error
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"The download could not complete - please make sure you are connected to eithre 3G or WiFi" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorView show];
    //if no connection network indicator not visible
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetalleEmpresaViewController *detailViewController =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailEmpresaViewController"];
    detailViewController.title =[[categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"idCategoria"];
    detailViewController.detalleDescription = [categorias objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Are you reloading the tables data? Posting your code would be helpful in finding out what you have / haven't done.

Comment: @BenAvery, I am reloading data only after JSON delegate methods

Comment: You should reload the data after the user has changed the text value @"valoracion" or when the detail viewed is closed.

Comment: @BenAvery, I have updated my question including cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: Okay. I see you have array of dictionaries. Try just put [self.tableView reloadData]; in `viewDidAppear` method.

Comment: @OlegSobolev, I have tried it before, and the value is not updated just putting it in viewDidAppear method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try call `[tableview reloadData]` method and make sure that you have correct implementation of tableview delegate methods.

If place where you change and save your JSON is another, than `tableViewController`, then put `reloadData` method in `viewDidAppear` of `tableViewController` class. If you saving JSON in other method of same `tableViewController`, then place `reloadData` in last line of this method.

Comment: I am populating the data via JSON, where should I put reload data?

Comment: After you **change and save** your JSON file or string or what is it. @mvasco

Comment: Helping to you will be easier if you show some code of your implementation of `UITableViewController` class. Methods lile `cellForRow`, etc.

Comment: I will update my question including cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: And method where you change and save your JSON. those methods are belong same controller? If not please note what the hierarchy of them. @mvasco

Comment: OK, I will put them all in my question.

Comment: All methods are now included in my question.

Comment: i have included [self.tableView reloadData] inside viewDidLoad method, and the value is not updated.

Comment: I said `viewDidAppear` method. @mvasco

Comment: Do you put NSDictionary to detailViewController, right? Maybe there happened copying of the dictionary? When you logging edited data in tableViewController do you see new data or old? @mvasco

Comment: Inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you can see I am defining the NSDictionary form tableViewController to detailViewController. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @mvasco
1)In detailViewController property of dictionary is not defined as (copy)?
2)After user change data and detailViewController call popToRootController method please put edited data in NSLog and tell me what you see - old data (hence problem in saving data or see step 1) or new data (hence problem in refreshing data)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48825/discussion-between-oleg-sobolev-and-mvasco)

Comment: What was the problem? @mvasco

Comment: The problem was my iOS simulator, it takes about 30 seconds to refresh the tableViewController....on a real device it is working fine putting the reload method on viewDidAppear.